# python matplotlib: mark dots over Line2D

Tags: python, matplotlib

i would like to mark some dots over a Line2D plot.
my markers are an indicators list.
(the format of the markers can be different, but i must have multiple markers).

for example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x_axis  = [...]
y_axis  = [1,2,3,4,5]
plt.plot(x_axis,y_axis)
marker1 = [0,0,1,0,0]
marker2 = [1,0,0,0,0]
# TODO: mark with green dots where marker1 == 1,
#       mark with red dots where marker2 ==1.
```

the way i walk around this problem is by making another plot 
(just messing around with the x and y axis to feet to the first plot).

anyway, pretty sure there is a right way to do so,
any ideas?

Comment: for colored points `plt.scatter(X, Y, 'g')`

Comment: thanks for the answer, its pretty much what i do for the walk around, this solution requires to do some ugly indexing of the Y axis. (the X values are x_axis[marker], and y's values are y_axis[marker]. the question is if there is a nice way to do it with the Line2D object or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can plot one graph per color, filtering the original array by the marker, which is pretty straight forward to implement:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x_axis  = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
y_axis  = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
plt.plot(x_axis,y_axis)
marker1 = np.array([0,0,1,0,0]).astype(bool)
marker2 = np.array([1,0,0,0,0]).astype(bool)

#       mark with green dots where marker1 == 1,
#       mark with red dots where marker2 ==1.
for m, c in zip([marker1, marker2],["g","r"]):
    plt.plot(x_axis[m], y_axis[m], color=c, ls="", marker="o")

plt.show()
```

[image]